# Is it true that Navagrahas should be worshiped after offering prayers to other Gods at temples?

Tags: temple, worship, navagraha

At Hindu  Temples, we see many dieties like Ganesha, Kartikeya (Muruga), Lord Shiva, Hanuman and Navagrahas. I heard that Navagrahas should be the worshiped only  after offering prayers to other Gods or deities and i follow it. Is this procedure true?

Comment: For the devotee-visitors or for the temple priests? I am not clear on this.

Comment: @Rickross in his original revision, he said he follows it, So, i think it is about devotees.

Comment: whoever going to pray hindu temples